# stop css target being affected by backbutton

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I use the target selector to put and remove a class that shows and hides the navigation menu. The problem is that when a user uses the backbutton on the browser the menu states get messed up.

This is my css code

```
<style>
#buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{display: none;}
#wrap:target #mainmenu{display: block;}
#wrap:target #buttons-container a.open-menu-primary{display: none;}
#wrap:target #buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{display: block;}
</style>
```

`buttons-container` is a div with two buttons, `open-menu-primary` & `close-menu-primary`, that toggle each other on and off and show or hide the mainmenu.

The problem occurs when someone uses the back button. In that case it only toggles the button states between open and close-menu-primary, which are a burger and a close image.

You can check the live version here if you make the browser small enough or use a mobile device, screen size has to be smaller than (min-width: 768px) and (min-height: 558px) [website with toggle by target selector](http://www.rieon.nl)

Hope someone can clear this up if it is possible to use target this way or if there better ways to get this affect without scripting please.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand and/or I cannot reproduce it. But note, if you modify the DOM and then navigate to another page, those changes will be lost when you go back to the page.

Comment: The back button changes the 'open-menu-primary' to 'close-menu-primary' and vise versa without affecting the menu class/state.

Answer (score 1):

The question is... when user presses the back button, do you want to go back one state of menu visibility (ie. hide it or unhide it), or do you want to go back one page?

I check your linked page http://www.rieon.nl. I think this is the problem:

I presume you want the user to go back one page, not just to hide the menu. Then, you need to change this piece of code

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#buttons-container a").click(function(){
        $("nav").toggleClass("main");
    });
});
```

and add either `return false` or `e.preventDefault()`:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#buttons-container a").click(function(e){
        $("nav").toggleClass("main");
        e.preventDefault();  // use either one
        return false;        // of these lines
    });
});
```

The problem is that by clicking on the link on navigation button, browser executes the javascript handler that shows the menu AND navigates to link's href address (which is #wrap) and that creates a new step in its history, so that when user hits back button, browser just goes back to previous state (which is usually the same page but without #wrap). By adding `return false` (that's jQuery speciality) or calling `preventDefault()` on event object (that's standard JS), you cancel the navigation and leave only your own handler to be executed.

Comment: I think you got it, for me it is qiuet new working with JQuery, but I am gonna test and try your sugestion. Many thanks Ondra so far I'll get back.

Comment: I forgot what I did, but the 'target selector' is only for toggling the 'close' and 'open' menu buttons. JQuery is toggles the clas 'main' for the navigation div, wich gives it a top position of 0px or 60px.  So the problem is that when you use the backbutton in your browser you change the "target' selector and change the button state but not the position of the navigation div wich is controlled by JQuery.  Is there a way to trigger the JQuery script when the backbuttons is hit. @Ondra, the 'e.preventDefault' makes no difference and 'return false' disables the 'target' selector.

Comment: should I go all the way with JQuery and change both the classes of 'buttons-container a.close-primary' and '.open-primary' as well as the nav. I rather would like to use a css solution and then use target aswell on the navigation but you can't set two different classes with one target selector or can you?